# creating dual ethernet connections with separate ip via usb

Tags: usb, ip, ethernet, adaptor

is it possible to set 2 separate ip addresses on a laptop by adding a USB network adaptor?

And if so, which one would you recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can have as more as network interfaces you want, I don't understand which one would you recommend part, but if I understood correctly I mean, if I suggest USB network adapter at all or not.

USB network adapters are restricted to USB speed, so if you have high speed internet and you want to use it with USB network adapter, it's not possible. I'm talking about 1GB, I think maximum speed you can get from USB network adapter is 300 MBits.

Comment: excellent! I was asking if there is a specific USB adaptor you would recommend to do the job. 
Thanks!